# Best Practices moving to Ember from Backbone

Tags: ember.js

I have inherited a Backbone app, running inside of Rails.  I am looking at converting the app to Ember, however the difficulty is that we can not pause development until the app is converted over.  Instead any new features will be built with Ember and as time permits, we will transition the old Backbone code over to Ember.  Because of this, both Backbone and Ember will need to exist within the same Rails app.

With name-spacing, I can not think of any possible issue that might arise with having both frameworks running side-by-side.  However, are there any best-practices related to this?  Or any known pitfalls to look out for?

Answer (score 0):

You primary issue will be library compatibility. ie:- jQuery used by Backbone vs Ember. Same for Handlebars, which on the Ember side is a hard dependency. Based on which version of Ember you are on you will need a different Handlebars. If you are using Backbone with `Backburner`, that might be a similar concern.

Other than that, you'll probably need to use the `rootElement` attribute with `Ember.Application.create` to tell ember to only stick to a custom part of DOM.